# How to compress PDF of invoice shipment and Creditmemo

Tags: magento2, pdf

In Magento 2.4.1 I developed below code to compress the PDF and it was working fine
Recently I updated Magento to 2.4.6-p3 and now compression stoped working.

> app/code/Vendor/CompressPDF/etc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice"
                type="Vendor\CompressPDF\Model\Sales\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
    
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/CompressPDF/Model/Sales/Order/Pdf

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CompressPDF\Model\Sales\Order\Pdf;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    /**
     * Set Font as Regular
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    /**
     * Set Font as Bold
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_BOLD);
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    /**
     * Set Font as Italic
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param  int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontItalic($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_ITALIC);
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }
}
```